# Key-Value image dto json request

Tags: json, httprequest

What is the best practice to send dto with multiple image.

First case, 1 level depth, example,

// lets say the key is jsondata

```
{
   "name" : "My Awesome Name",
   "age"  : 20
}
```

//and each image has its own key

face_only_image : face-image-here
full_body_image : full-body-image-here

in this case im using multipart, send the json as string, and each image with key, easy.

the problem is when i want to send the 2 level depth, example.

```
{
   "employee_name" : "My Awesome Name",

   "added_items": [ // this has dynamic size
      {
          "title" : "Super Smash Dudes"
          "image" : "image-here" // real image, not just the url
      },
      {
          "title" : "God of Peace"
          "image" : "image-here" // real image, not just the url
      },
      {
          "title" : "Steampunk 2077"
          "image" : "image-here" // real image, not just the url
      }
   ]
}
```

Most effective yet best practices to sending 2 level depth multiple image.

**Im using Spring with java as backend, and postman to sending request**

Could anyone help me, please.